# How to use array_agg() in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to use array_agg() function with sequelize. How can I do that ?
I have been used below code, but it doesn't work.

```
let statusTabs = await Parameters.findAll({
    where: {
        param_key: 't_status',
        param_name: ['Washing', 'Awaiting', 'Pending']
    },
    attributes: [
        sequelize.literal('array_agg(param_key)'),
        sequelize.fn('array_agg', sequelize.col('param_key'))
    ]
});
```

It is giving errors like below -

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined**

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'literal' of undefined**

How can I get array_agg() to work ?

Comment: I got the issue. The issue was regarding sequelize instance. It was not getting the proper instance of it.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
Zone.findAll({
  attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('array_agg', Sequelize.col('city')), 'zones']],
  where: { country: 'Canada' },
  group: ['country']
})
```